# i want my chef-client to run automatically when i change my cookbook with logs

Tags: chef-infra

I have wrote a cookbook to create two directories and i have bootstrapped it, i can see two directories are created on node, i have edited my cookbook like i have added one more directories to it, i want my node to understand that changes are made in cookbook and i have to run chef-client.

for this i have added chef-client::default in my run list and edited the 
`node["chef_client"]["interval"]` attribute to 5 min(300).

but nothing happened, manually i have run

```
chef-client -j /etc/chef/first-boot.json
```

but no progress.

Kindly help.

Recipe:

```
directory "/root/testfolder" do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 0755
  action :create
end

directory "/root/crontestfolder" do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 0755
  action :create
end
directory "/root/testfolder1" do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 0755
  action :create
end
directory "#{node['test']['filename']}" do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 0755
  action :create
end
```

Logs

````
2014-09-16T12:32:37+00:00] WARN:
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
SSL validation of HTTPS requests is disabled. HTTPS connections are still
encrypted, but chef is not able to detect forged replies or man in the middle
attacks.

To fix this issue add an entry like this to your configuration file:

```
  # Verify all HTTPS connections (recommended)
  ssl_verify_mode :verify_peer

  # OR, Verify only connections to chef-server
  verify_api_cert true
```

To check your SSL configuration, or troubleshoot errors, you can use the
`knife ssl check` command like so:

```
  knife ssl check -c /etc/chef/client.rb
```

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

Starting Chef Client, version 11.12.2
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["test::default", "chef-client::default"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - chef_handler
  - windows
  - logrotate
  - cron
  - chef-client
  - test
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 11 resources
Recipe: test::default
  * directory[/root/testfolder] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/root/testfolder1] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/root/redis] action create (up to date)
Recipe: chef-client::init_service
  * directory[/var/run/chef] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/cache/chef] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/lib/chef] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/log/chef] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/etc/chef] action create (up to date)
  * template[/etc/init.d/chef-client] action create (up to date)
  * template[/etc/sysconfig/chef-client] action create (up to date)
  * service[chef-client] action enable (up to date)
  * service[chef-client] action start (up to date)

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete

Chef Client finished, 0/12 resources updated in 6.426809584 seconds
````

Comment: are you do this directly on a node? or via something like chef-solo in vagrant?   Also did you update the metadata.rb on the cookbook adjust the version?

Comment: With chef-client::default in the run list, it should have configured your chef client to run as a service. If you uploaded your cookbook to the chef server the change should be took. But please describe your env, are you using hosted chef or open source chef server ? using chef-solo (doubt from your command) did you upload the updated cookbook ? Guessing all that (and other things) will give you as many answers on your problem as there is possible guess for thoose questions

Comment: @Tensibai open source chef, yes I did uploaded.

Comment: Could you share a log of the chef run and the extract of your recipe ? (edit the question to add this)

Comment: @Doon yes i run chef-client -j /etc/chef/first-boot.json on node, I am using opensource chef server, yes I have updated the cookbook.

Comment: @Tensibai as u can see in the logs there is no folder called crontestfolder created

Comment: As @Doon said, update the cookbook version in its metadata.rb, upload to the chef server and retry. with a version bump it will enforce a sync of the cookbook, which could be not done if the last download is recent (I don't know the policy cache time exactly and sometimes chef client did not catch the recipe update without a version bump)

Comment: @Tensibai no progess, I have updated the cookbook version from 0.1.0 to 0.1.1 in metadata.rb and uploaded it to chef server. but still no progress, am I missing anything pls guide

Comment: @user60679 appart running with -l debug to gather some more inforamtions I see no reason it does not takes it into account, just to be sure: do you have any version lock in the environment ? it could be the reason, but I really don't see why. Maybe you can have a better help on irc (irc.freenode.net channel #chef) as it seems more a config problem than a coding problem for this site.

Comment: just run chef-client by itself )( no -j /etc/chef/first-boot.json)  and then look a the output, and see what version of your cookbook is being run. you should be making changes to the run list on the server, not the client

Answer (score 1):

Two high probabilities:

1. You are not updating the version of your cookbook, and the cookbook is 'frozen' on your server.  As a result, you think you are pushing the new cookbook, but you are not actually.
2. You are updating the version, but you have your environment locked down to a specific version of the cookbook.

The first thing I would do is log into the node and check the contents of `/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/test/metadata.rb` and `/var/chef/cache/coobooks/test/recipes/default.rb`.
If those files don't match what you have on your development box, then one of the above issues is almost certainly your problem.  If they do match what you expect, then you have a code issue.